# Symfony3 Custom Validation Constraints with parameters throw Exception

Tags: php, validation, constraints, symfony

I've been trying to create a custom validation constraint with parameters, using services on Symfony3.

The problem is that I get an exception after submitting my form :

`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to OC\PlatformBundle\Validator\AntifloodValidator::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 71 and defined`

I understand Symfony couldn't hydrate the AntifloodValidator's constructor with the parameters given in services.yml.

Here is my code :

In services.yml :

```
oc_platform.validator.antiflood:
        class: OC\PlatformBundle\Validator\AntifloodValidator
        arguments: ['@request_stack', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: oc_platform_antiflood }
```

In Antiflood.php :

```
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Antiflood extends Constraint
{
  public $message = "Vous avez déjà posté un message il y a moins de 15 secondes, merci d'attendre un peu.";

  public function validateBy()
  {
    return 'oc_platform_antiflood'; // Ici, on fait appel à l'alias du service
  }
}
```

In AntifloodValidator.php :

```
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Validator;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class AntifloodValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
  private $requestStack;
  private $em;

  // Les arguments déclarés dans la définition du service arrivent au constructeur
  // On doit les enregistrer dans l'objet pour pouvoir s'en resservir dans la méthode validate()
  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $em)
  {
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    $this->em           = $em;
  }

  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
  {
   ...
```

And in Advert.php (my Entity) :

```
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

use OC\PlatformBundle\Validator as CustomAssert;

/**
 * Advert
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OC\PlatformBundle\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="title", message="Une annonce existe déjà avec ce titre.")
 */
class Advert
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
   * @Assert\DateTime()
   */
  private $date;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, unique=false)
   * @Assert\Length(min=10)
   */
  private $title;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
   * @Assert\Length(min=2)
   */
  private $author;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
   * @Assert\NotBlank()
   * @CustomAssert\Antiflood
   */
  private $content;
```

In went through the documentation multiple times and didn't find anything. Same thing here on stackoverflow.

Any idea ?

Comment: Is the `oc_platform.validator.antiflood` actually registered in your service container? You can use the `debug:container` command to check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are injecting to your service (Constraint) the request stack it should have a request scope like this :

```
oc_platform.validator.antiflood:
        class: OC\PlatformBundle\Validator\AntifloodValidator
        arguments: ['@request_stack', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: oc_platform_antiflood }
        scope: request
```

Comment: Weird. I didn't see it written in the doc : [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html). It doesn't resolve my problem though. Why is it necessary ?

Comment: Yeah I think you should add it because if you are injecting a request stack in your service so he noud to be request scoped which mean that your service will have the same life time as your request

Comment: The request stack was precisely introduced to get rid of the request scope (the whole scope concept is deprecated since Symfony 2.8 and was removed with Symfony 3).

Comment: I see. But if it's decrepated, why does [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) still talk about it without warning about its decrepation ?

Comment: xabbuh is write it's deprecated just here is the correct link of doc http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Comment: Ooh, I see ! Thank you, elkorchi anas. Still no idea about my bug, though ?

Answer (score 1):

In the **Antiflood** class, the function must be named validate**d**By, and not validateBy...